# Adding procedure in database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure that adds data into two tables at the same time but using mySQL, but I don't have much experience using if/else statement in database so could someone tell me how I can fix my code

Here the Attributes:

```
Customer information: ID,Name, Address, Telephone.

Staff information: ID, Name, Phone

Camera/Len Type: ID,Name

Camera: ID, typeID, Model, Status, Color, Hiring Price (per day), Paying Price (in case of loss).

Len: ID, TypeID, Model, Status, Hiring Price (per day), Paying Price (in case of loss).

Order orderID, customerID, employeeID, hireDate, returnDate

OrderDetail: orderID, cameraID, lenID, cameraQuantity, lenQuantity, Status(paid/not paid), pStatus(Lost/Ok)
```

Here's the Procedure code:

```
 DELIMITER $$
 Create Procedure addOrder(IN cust_id int, IN camera_id int, IN len_id int, 
 IN emp_id int, IN c_quantity int,IN l_quantity int,
 IN status char(30), IN p_Status char(30), IN hire_date date, IN return_date 
 date)
 begin
 Declare order_id int;
 Declare hireTime int;
 Declare totalC int;
 Declare totalL int;
 Declare totalP int;

 Select order_id = max(orderID) from orders;
 if orderID is null then set order_id = 1;

 Set hireTime = DATEDILL(hire_date, return_date);
 if hire_date == return_date then set hireTime = 1;

 if p_Status = "Lost" then set
    select totalC = hireTime*c_quantity*hPrice + pPrice from Camera as C
    inner join orderDetail as OD on C.camID = OD.camera_id inner join Orders 
    as O on O.orderID = OD.order_id;

    select totalL = hireTime*l_quantity*hPrice + pPrice from Lens as L
    inner join orderDetail as OD on L.lenID = OD.len_id inner join Orders as 
    O on O.orderID = OD.order_id;

    Set totalP = totalL + totalC;
else set
    select totalC = hireTime*c_quantity*hPrice + pPrice from Camera as C
    inner join orderDetail as OD on C.camID = OD.camera_id inner join Orders 
    as O on O.orderID = OD.order_id;

    select totalL = hireTime*l_quantity*hPrice + pPrice from Lens as L
    inner join orderDetail as OD on L.lenID = OD.len_id inner join Orders as 
    O on O.orderID = OD.order_id;

    Set totalP = totalL + totalC;
end if;

insert into Orders(custID, empID, hireDate, returnDate) 
    values (cust_id, emp_id,hire_date, return_date);

insert into orderDetail(orderID, cameraID, lenID, totalPrice, camQuantity, 
lenQuantity, status, pStatus) values (order_id,camera_id, len_id, totalP, 
c_quantity, l_quantity, status, p_Status);
end $$
DELIMITER
```

Comment: You intend to call this for every row of order details?

Comment: There are some obvious problems here, there is no datedill function - you probably mean datediff, the null safe equal should be <=> not ==, the set statement after the if .. then and else is incorrect in that it does not set anything, why are you referencing orders in the select statements when you don't appears to be using anything from this table, if you are calling this for every order detail then you probably don't want to insert to orders everytime. It would help if you could publish sample data in your question as text with expected result or to sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to use view table to add all tables after that use stored procedure. And I give you and example I think u can figure out.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CMIDByID] @UID INT, @TID INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @CMID INT

IF(@TID IS NULL AND @UID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT @TID = TID, @CMID = CMID FROM tbl_U WHERE UID = @UID     
END


IF (@CMID IS NULL AND @TID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT @CMID = CMID FROM tbl_T WHERE TID = @TID
END

SELECT @CMID
END
```

Comment: This is a sqlserver answer but the question is for mysql - there are significant differences.